# Is there a way to find my laptop screen's pressure sensitivity rating through windows 11?

Tags: command-line, laptop, touchscreen, device-manager, stylus

Recently purchased a Asus Flow x16 laptop, and I am trying to figure out the screen pressure sensitivity rating to buy a corresponding stylus. There is nothing in the manuals, online reviews, or the tech specs from Asus website. Is there a manually way to find out through the command line or device manager?

Comment: If you're looking for whether stylus features are supported, you can check for your model here: https://rog.asus.com/support/FAQ/1047361. Otherwise I'd suggest contacting their support for details: https://www.asus.com/support/Product/ContactUs/Services/questionform/

Answer (score 0):

Likely none of the above.

Fingertip touch is a capacitive contact issue and either light touch or no (but close) touch.

Stylus is much the same, assuming you can use a Stylus on your screen. Likely you can, but do check.

So there is not a rating so far as I know (I have a touch screen), but LIGHT touch is always the order of the day.

Almost for sure you cannot determine the pressure your stylus or finger exerts either.